Cant get Audience page in google Ads?
Trying to exclude an audience from my campaign and Google tells me oh easy! go to Audience, Keywords and content and click on audience.

...The button is just not there. Is there anything that needs to happen before it will show up? Or was the button moved somewhere?

What happens if you go directly to the URL https://ads.google.com/aw/audiences/summary ?

Goes to the overview page
